# Android Studio: Create a simple Library and import in project

Tags: android, gradle, build, aar

I want to create a simple library which will have a custom font in the EditText and then import it in another project.
I am using Android Studio.
I tried building aar from studio as well as gradle from command prompt.
I could generate the 'aar' file but after importing, the resource identifiers are not detected.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you create a `Module` in `AS`? And add as Library in your Project.

Comment: I  created a module while writing my library code. but now I want a portable JAR or AAR file. Not sure how to do that properly....

Answer (score 0):

First: Create a Android module in Android Studio. Here you can put your clases. In your gradle file (for this module) you can also import other third libraries you need.

Second: Import this library in your application module (usually called app). For getting this, in your app gradle file (dependendies section):

```
dependencies{    
 compile project(':yourLibraryName')
}
```

Comment: But I want to create a portable JAR / AAR file..... How to do that ? (I created a new module from similar steps.....upon building my project, the AAR file got created in the build folder but I couldnt import the classes from it, i.e. the package is empty except the manifest file)